# SVG filter: center a blended image

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have an SVG filter that overlays an image with a spinner.  This works fine, except I cannot figure out how to center the spinner on the image.  The logical answer seems to be:

```
<filter id="loading" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <feImage xlink:href="filters.svg#loading-overlay" x="50%" y="50%" result="spinner" />
  <feOffset in="spinner" result="offsetSpinner" dx="-25px" dy="-25px" />
  <feBlend in2="SourceGraphic" in="offsetSpinner" />
</filter>
```

But of course you can't use "-25px" as an argument to feOffset.

Anybody have a clever solution?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pytmd8tr/

(As a matter of opinion - I think the way primitiveUnits works is really stupid.  In particular, it makes no sense to specify things like the stdev of a blur as a % of the original image.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use JavaScript to calculate the right %'s and insert them, but failing that - something like this should work. (Although feImage sizing & positioning can have bugs in IE10).

```
 <filter id="loading" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <feImage xlink:href="#loading-overlay" x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%" result="spinner" />
      <feBlend in2="SourceGraphic" in="spinner" result="foo" />
    </filter>
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but won't that make the spinner a different size depending on the image it's applied to?

Comment: Yes. If you want fixed size and relative positioning then there's no way to do this in a filter without javascript - which is not the end of the world